# Collapsing/expanding main component if any of module is enabled/disabled in joomla 2.5 custom template

Tags: layout, module, twitter-bootstrap-3, joomla2.5, joomla-template

I have made a custom (Joomla 2.5.20) template. I have used Bootstrap 3 framework for my front end coding. I have a 4 column layout with 3 modules and a main component. The issue is when I disable/enable any of my module the main component should collapse/expand according to the layout.

I have used the following condition in the head but not finding the result but the solution is in the condition because I am not able to make ("and / or") logic.

```
    <?php 
    if ($this->countModules('Left and special and Right'))
{
   $span = "col-md-3";
}
elseif (!$this->countModules('Left and special'))
{
   $span = "col-md-6";
}
elseif (!$this->countModules('Left and Right'))
{
   $span = "col-md-6";
}
elseif (!$this->countModules('special and Right'))
{
   $span = "col-md-6";
}
else
{
   $span = "col-md-12";
}
    ?>
```

The module positions in the body is correct so I think it would be appropriate not mentioning it.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<?php 
if ($this->countModules('Left and special and Right'))
{
   $span = "col-md-3";
}
elseif ($this->countModules('Left and special')) || ($this->countModules('Left and Right')) || ($this->countModules('Right and special'))
{
   $span = "col-md-6";
}
elseif ($this->countModules('Left)) || ($this->countModules('Right')) || ($this->countModules('special'))
{
   $span = "col-md-9";
}
else
{
   $span = "col-md-12";
}
?>
```